# index zero in R subsetting

Tags: r, indexing, subset

In R, when trying to subset a object, e.g. data.frame or vector, if too big index is used, return value will be NA. This part is OK.

However if we use zero as index, the result is not NA but something else.

example:

```
a<-c(1,2,3)
a[4]
[1] NA
a[0]
numeric(0)
```

Can anyone enlighten me the reason for this issue? Why index zero will return this "numeric(0)"?

Comment: https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/design-flaws-in-r-3-%E2%80%94-zero-subscripts/

Comment: @BenBolker The wackiest thing there, assigning a value to a[0] and then getting it back, seems to have been fixed as a bug. Doesn't give an error message though.

Comment: @BenBolker , Spacedman is correct, that now assigning a value to a[0] will not make what described in the article from your link happen. I guess this bug was fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [R language definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) says

> A special case is the zero index, which has null effects: x[0] is an empty vector and otherwise including zeros among positive or negative indices has the same effect as if they were omitted.

This convention goes back to R's predecessor S (see Venables and Ripley *S Programming* on [Google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-rKWRH0fglMC&pg=PA24&dq=S+zero+index&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8TjKVK6dNsaUNtSBg_AN&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=S%20zero%20index&f=false)).

This does not answer "why?" (and you [are not the only one who thinks this is a bad idea](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/design-flaws-in-r-3-%E2%80%94-zero-subscripts/)), but it does clearly state that it's intentional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate the information from R lang definition and extra source. However as @Spacedman mentioned, the bug might have already been fixed.